# Does Lightbringer illuminate or dispel the Darkness spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, vision-and-light, lost-mine-of-phandelver

[Lightbringer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/lightbringer) is a +1 mace that appears in the *Lost Mine of Phandelver* adventure.

> It's found on the worktable by the Forge of Spells in Wave Echo Cave (p. 48).

The description says:

> This +1 mace was made for a cleric of Lathander, the god of dawn. The head of the mace is shaped like a sunburst and made of solid brass. Named Lightbringer, **this weapon glows as bright as a torch when its wielder commands**. While glowing, the mace deals an extra 1d6 radiant damage to undead creatures.

I'm playing a warlock who cast the *darkness* spell at 4th level. My party member used Lightbringer in the area of *darkness* in order to reveal my location.

**Can Lightbringer dispel, suppress, or pierce through the darkness created by a 4th-level *darkness* spell?**

Comment: Related question: [What is considered magical light for the purposes of the Darkness spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/89888/what-is-considered-magical-light-for-the-purposes-of-the-darkness-spell)

Answer (score 15):

#### It can illuminate an area of a *darkness* spell, as light from a magic item is magical light.

As per the *darkness* spell description, it blocks non-magical light:

> A creature with darkvision can't see through this darkness, and **nonmagical light can't illuminate it**.

But does it explicitly allow magical light? **Yes.** Jeremy Crawford, whose rulings are considered official, says in [two](https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/949114071571341314) [tweets](https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/949354834947289088):

> **Light from any magical source** can illuminate the area of a darkness spell, but the darkness spell can dispel light created by a spell of 2nd level or lower, not light created by a non-spell.
>
> If a source of magical light is **not a spell of 2nd level or lower**, darkness can be illuminated by that light.

Is light from a magic item "magical light"? According to our question [What is considered magical light for the purposes of the Darkness spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/89888/what-is-considered-magical-light-for-the-purposes-of-the-darkness-spell), light from a magic item is magical light.

I concur with this assessment. Words with no game rule meaning in D&D 5th edition (i.e. "magical light" isn't defined anywhere in the books) are interpreted by their natural English meaning. A magic item is clearly a "magical source", and I think it would be difficult to argue that light produced directly by a magic item is nonmagical.

Note that the level of a *darkness* spell doesn't have any effect, citing another [Crawford tweet](https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/524712732528873472):

> As written, the darkness spell can't be made more powerful with a higher level slot.

Therefore, Lightbringer, being magical, can illuminate an area affected by the *darkness* spell, regardless of level.

It can't actually dispel (i.e. end) the *darkness* spell, since no part of the item's description says it can. If you take Lightbringer back out of the area, for example, the darkness effect returns.

Answer (score 0):

## RAW: No, it wouldn't illuminate or dispel *darkness*. There is no effect saying this specifically.

The lightbringer +1 mace from the starter set game *Lost Mines of Phandelver* can't remove the effects of the *darkness* spell and neither can any other magical weapon.

[Jeremy Crawford's tweet](https://mobile.twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/722870799082721280) is fairly clear on the subject:

> Darkness cares only about light created by a spell.

Fairly simple. If it's not a spell then it doesn't work.

Comment: *Lightbringer* has nothing to do with the *light* cantrip. You are correct that it wouldn't dispel *darkness* - but *Lightbringer* (and/or its light) is not a spell.

Comment: And regarding your current last paragraph about *Lightbringer* not mentioning its brightness: *Lightbringer* says it "glows as bright as a torch" - and [torches](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/torch) give off 20 feet of bright light and 20 more feet of dim light.

Comment: I really don't understand what *light* has to do at all with this answer. It simply is not related to the weapon in any way and has no bearing on the topic at hand. It is completely wrong to associate the light effect of the weapon with any spell.

Comment: I have adjusted my answer to better fit the rules @V2Blast