# Does the Sacred Weapon from the Channel Divinity of Devotion Paladin dispel Darkness?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, paladin

This is a tricky one, and I haven't found a similar Q&A, but may have missed it.

Devotion paladins have a Channel Divinity option of Sacred Weapon that emits light 20/20 of bright/dim. Does this dispel *darkness*?

Comment: Related: "[What is considered magical light for the purposes of the Darkness spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/89888)" and "[Does Lightbringer illuminate or dispel the Darkness spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/133474)" and "[Does light from a flame from a magic weapon dispel Darkness?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/104149)"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## It can illuminate parts of the *darkness*, but does not dispel it

Firstly, magical light sources dispelling *darkness* is a function of that light source (and its text and spell level). For instance *daylight* can dispel it because of its own text (as long as it is cast at an equal or higher level). There is no general rule for *darkness*-dispelling.

However, [*darkness*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/darkness) only limits non-magical light from illuminating the area:

> ... and nonmagical light can't illuminate it.

And the effects (here, the light) of a Channel Divinity is magical, per the description of the [Channel Divinity](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/paladin#SacredOath-266) feature in general:

> Your oath allows you to channel divine energy to fuel magical effects.
>
> — *Player's Handbook* p. 85

So the light can illuminate parts of the area, but have no ability to dispel the spell.